# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mkdir, fileutils

I have a model `Report` to export all the Pdf attachments done for the bills. I have other models `Bill`, `Upload`.

`Bill has many uploads`

##### Tech Stack used

Ruby 2.5.8
Rails 5.0.7

##### Dummy Code

```
  require 'fileutils'
  require 'zip'
  require 'open-uri'

  class Report < ApplicationRecord
    
    def to_a  

      main_dir = "tmp/Attachment-#{self.id}"

      FileUtils::mkdir_p main_dir

      bills.each do |bill|
        bill_directory_name = "Bill_#{bill.id}"

        bill.uploads.each do |bill_upload|
            FileUtils::cd main_dir do
              FileUtils::mkdir_p "#{bill_directory_name}"

              file = open(bill_upload.file.url, 'rb')

              upload_name = "Invoice-#{bill_upload.file_file_name}-#{bill_upload.id}"
              FileUtils::cd "#{bill_directory_name}" do
                IO.copy_stream(file, "#{upload_name}")
              end
           end
        end
      end

      path = "tmp/Attachment-#{self.id}"
      archive = File.join(path, "Attachment-#{self.id}" + '.zip')
      FileUtils.rm archive, force: true

      Zip::File::open(archive, 'w') do |zipfile|
        Dir["#{path}/**/**"].reject{|f| f==archive }.each do |file|
          zipfile.add(file.sub(path + '/', ''), file)
        end
      end
    end
 end
```

##### Task

I am creating main directory `tmp/Attachment-#{self.id}`. Inside it, I am creating multiple billing directories (`bill_directory_name`) for the bills. And inside each of the billing directories I am including uploaded invoice after reading actual invoice saved inside `upload` model. And Final zip folder is created, archived and downloaded.

##### Problem

When I execute my code only once, it works perfect.

But if I execute it multiple times in multi threading environment then it says `No such file or directory`.

##### Following are the errors

/Users/siv/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:122: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block

WARN: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - test-1111-Sup-14-invoice

WARN: /Users/siv/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:122:in `chdir'

/Users/siv/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:122:in `cd'

/Users/siv/proj/app/models/report.rb:46:in `block in to_a'

> > Error in this line: bill.uploads.each do |bill_upload|

/Users/siv/proj/app/models/report.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in to_a'

> > Error in this line: FileUtils::cd main_dir do

/Users/siv/script/proj/app/models/report.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in to_a'

> > Error in this line: FileUtils::cd "#{bill_directory_name}" do

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe FileUtils makes use of Dir for the chdir/cd method,  and while it may not be documented in FileUtils, it is documented in Dir that cd/chdir is not thread safe.

> If a block is given, it is passed the name of the new current
> directory, and the block is executed with that as the current
> directory. The original working directory is restored when the block
> exits. The return value of chdir is the value of the block. chdir
> blocks can be nested, but in a multi-threaded program an error will be
> raised if a thread attempts to open a chdir block while another thread
> has one open or a call to chdir without a block occurs inside a block
> passed to chdir (even in the same thread).

https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-chdir

Comment: Yes it's not thread safe.

Comment: Is there other solution or logic to overcome this issue?